# How do I design this rectangle in Photoshop CC 2017 or Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Just need to know how to give the rectangle this shade kind of effect at the very ending and I also need to know how to cut the bottom line. I need info on exactly how to replicate this amazing rectangle designed by the TypeForm website.

I am not replicating them for a project but for my educational purpose.

Thanks in Advance
[image]

Comment: Rasterizing the rectangle and removing the bottom line 
Than I tried to drop shadow using angles which failed to give similar results.

Comment: You basically need an [**Opacity Mask**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-opacity-masks-transparency.html) in Illustrator or a [**Layer Mask**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html) in Photoshop.

Answer (score 4):

This is for illustrator. Draw a rounded rectangle, apply stroke and fill as required. Use an Outer Glow effect on the rectangle.

Draw a filled black rectangle to use as a transparency mask, and apply a Gaussian blur effect to it, then use that as the transparency mask.

[image]